# AngularJS: How to inherit the scope the directive locates in, and get attributes value same time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Could anybody help with this? Is there a way to access the scope the directive located in (e.g. a controller's scope) while I still can access the attributes' value.

here is my directive code

```
app.controller("someCtr", function( $scope ){
    $scope.controllerScopeVariable = "Lorem";
});
app.directive('myDirective', [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        directiveAttributeValue: "="
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var bar = scope['directiveAttributeValue'];
        var foo = scope['controllerScopeVariable']; //I need to access this
    }
   };
}]);
```

and here is the HTML:

```
    <div ng-controller="someCtr">
        <div myDirective directiveAttributeValue="{{blabla}}">
        </div>
    </div>
```

In the directive I cannot access the scope['controllerScopeVariable']. How can I do that?

Comment: Isolated scope (`scope.$new(true)`) does _not_ inherit from parent scope. You could look at other scope options like `scope:true` you get inherited child scope of its parent. And you could always read the attribute value using `attrs` and you could do `attrs['directiveAttributeValue']` or `scope.$eval(attrs['directiveAttributeValue'])` How ever if you have inherited from parent scope you wouldn't need it.

Comment: You also have a typo attribute must be `directive-attribute-value` inorder to be able to access it as `attrs['directiveAttributeValue']` or `scope.directiveAttributeValue` in your case

Comment: You have lots of typoes as well... http://plnkr.co/edit/zwbgdY?p=preview

Comment: Great the attrs with scope:true solves the problem. Thanks. But shouldn't I set scope to false? doesn't it have performance issues with scope:true?

Comment: `scope:false` just takes the parent scope, meaning you wont be able to use multiple of the same directive on the same parent (depends on how you are using it). What perf issue with `scope:true` ?

Comment: @PSL, I mean, the `scope:false` will let me use the same scope instance for all directive's instances on page, while `scope:true` will create a new instance of scope for each directive's instance, this consumes memory (in big Apps).

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the variable `controllerScopeVariable` also in the `scope` property of your directive.

For example:

```
    app.controller("someCtr", function( $scope ){
    $scope.controllerScopeVariable = "Lorem";
});
app.directive('myDirective', [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        directiveAttributeValue: "=",
        controllerScopeVariable: "&"
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var bar = scope['directiveAttributeValue'];
        var foo = scope['controllerScopeVariable'];
    }
   };
}]);
```

Keep in mind there will be three ways to define local scope properties you can pass:

- @  Used to pass a string value into the directive
- =    Used to create a two-way binding to an object that is passed into the directive
- &    Allows an external function to be passed into the directive and invoked